# If I build my own trello power up, can I use it for free?

Tags: trello

I started using Trello, and I need some feature for which I need power ups, but I do not want to pay.
If I build my own power up, will I be able to use it for free or it counts as a "regular" power up?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free Trello accounts are entitled "One Power-Up per Board" as described on the [Trello pricing](https://trello.com/pricing) page. That one Power-Up can be a custom or a market/regular one, but the limit applies the same.

Potentially you could build one custom Power-Up that does all the various functions you want to get around the limitation.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "custom" category under Power-Ups any longer. Is this now a paid feature?

Answer (score 0):

Free accounts can now have as many power-ups as they like on their boards. And yes, if you write your own power-up you can choose whether you charge yourself or not :)
There are also a lot of [free power-ups](https://www.bluecatreports.com/free-trello-powerups/) you can use these days so do check the list there in case you can save yourself the development effort ;)